# how to write data to the existing xml file using code in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

friends i am downloading some images from website using xmlrpc now i want write the url of those images into xml files how to add data to exiting xml file in android

Comment: Where does the xml file exist? Is it prestored in res directory or manually created during application lifetime?

Comment: Follow this thread on how to write xml on Android:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android

Comment: it is already prestored in res directory, just now i found one solution i.e we have 


import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

we have the above class to write to an xml file from version 8 onwards but what should i do for earlier versions, if u have a solution plz help me,