# How can I transform xml to html on android?

Tags: java, html, android, xml, transform

I'm relatively new to java and android, in my android application I need to get an XML file, transform it and show it to a user.

I know how to parse XML, but I don't want to parse it and generate views after. I'd like to transform it to an HTML and display in a WebView.

I'm trying to find something on the Internet but can't find anything.

How can I do it? Any ideas or links will be appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual tool to use for transforming XML to HTML is XSLT. Search SO for XSLT tutorial and you'll get some good results.

[Here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718381/xslt-transforming-performance) showing how one developer used XSLT on Android. 
You can also search for examples of the use of [Transformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) in Java, as in [this helpful article](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/java/news/javaxslt_0801.html):

```
// JAXP reads data using the Source interface
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);

// the factory pattern supports different XSLT processors
TransformerFactory transFact =
        TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

trans.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(System.out));
```

**Update:**
For older versions of the Android java API:
[This article](http://ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html) shows how to use a [SAX parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) to parse the input XML, then use [XmlSerializer](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html) to output XML. The latter could easily output whatever XHTML you want. Both are available since API level 1.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to do XPath in API level 3, but if your input XML isn't too complex you should be able to code your own transformations. I know you "don't want to parse it and generate view after", but if you mean you don't want to even use an XML parser that's provided by Android, then I don't know of any alternative.

**Update 2:**
I just learned about [XOM, which supports a subset of XPath](http://www.xom.nu/). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android) shows someone using XOM on Android (to write XML) with API level 4. You could take advantage of the XPath features, as well as the serialization features. It requires a small external library, XOM's jar. I don't know if it's compatible with API level 3.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, I know about XSLT but as I understood it is not supported in android (I could not find anything about it neither in SO nor in Google) . About code you provided, android does not provide the javax.xml.transform package, so I can't use all this classes. I've read that it is not recommended to add external classes to android. Is it true?

Comment: Ok, despite recommendations, I imported this package, now I'm getting `Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1`

Comment: @Burjua: "android does not provide the javax.xml.transform package" What version of the API are you using? The android doc I linked to says "since API level 8".

Comment: Actualy I'm using API level 3 as I want android since 1.5 to be able to run my application. Indeed after I changed project build target it works, but what about older versions of android?

Comment: @Burjua, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html shows how to use a SAX parser to parse the input XML, then use XmlSerializer to output XML. The latter could easily output whatever XHTML you want. Both are available since API level 1.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a great answer and comments, I didn't want to parse xml, but apparently I will have to. If you or anyone else have other ideas, please post them))

Answer (score 0):

Please see the complete working example, created as a part of "AndStatus" application.
It uses XSLT to show localized (!) Application Change Log in a WebView of the HelpActivity.

The working example consists of these parts:

1. The small utility class without any dependencies (i.e. it may be easily reused) which has this function:

   /**

   - Transform XML input files using supplied XSL stylesheet and show it in the WebView
   - @param activity Activity hosting the WebView
   - @param resView WebView in which the output should be shown
   - @param resXml XML file to transform. This file is localized! It should be put into "raw-" folder
   - @param resXsl XSL stylesheet. In the "raw" folder. May be single for all languages...
     */
     public static void toWebView(Activity activity, int resView, int resXml, int resXsl) {
     ...
     }
     See full source code here: [Xslt.java](https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/src/org/andstatus/app/util/Xslt.java)
2. The example of its usage: See [HelpActivity.java](https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/src/org/andstatus/app/HelpActivity.java)
3. The XML file to be transformed: [changes.xml](https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/res/raw/changes.xml)
   and the corresponding XSL stylesheet: [changesxsl.xsl](https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/res/raw/changesxsl.xsl)

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT, XSLT convert your XML in to HTML that we can display in Android Webview.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318998/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-and-display-it-in-android-webview/19402040#19402040)  will help.