# How Writing XMl file usning XMLStreamWriter in android

Tags: android

i want create XML file here is my following code

```
String fileName = "jasstech.xml";
XMLOutputFactory xof =  XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter xtw = null;**

try    
{

  xtw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), "UTF-8");    
  xtw.writeStartDocument("UTF-8", "1.0");    
  xtw.writeStartElement("root");    
  xtw.writeComment("This is an attempt to create an XML file with StAX");    
  xtw.writeStartElement("foo");    
  xtw.writeAttribute("order", "1");
  xtw.writeStartElement("meuh");
  xtw.writeAttribute("active", "true");
  xtw.writeCharacters("The cows are flying high this Spring");
  xtw.writeEndElement();
  xtw.writeEndElement();
  xtw.writeStartElement("bar");
  xtw.writeAttribute("order", "2");
  xtw.writeStartElement("tcho");
  xtw.writeAttribute("kola", "K");
  xtw.writeCharacters("Content of tcho tag");
  xtw.writeEndElement();
  xtw.writeEndElement();
  xtw.writeEndElement();
  xtw.writeEndDocument();

}

catch (XMLStreamException e)
{

  e.printStackTrace();
}

catch (IOException ie)
{
  ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above 
Same Code is Working Fine in JAVA project 
But In Android Project gives following Error

```
03-03 07:48:40.778: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-03 07:48:40.788: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719): com.kochar.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory not found
03-03 07:48:40.788: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(719):     at com.kochar.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.newInstance(XMLOutputFactory.java:23)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XMLStreamWriter` is in the `javax.xml.stream.*` package.  This package is not included in the default Android build.  You can use it, but you have to repackage it in your app.

Description of your problem and a guide on how to repackage javax.* packages:  http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages

If you don't want to repackage `XMLStreamWriter` in your app, try using `XmlSerializer` which is included in Android.  Excellent example right here on SO:  [Writing XML on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android/2296051#2296051)