# Simple ODT in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio, odt, opendocument

I would like to try to create an OpenDocument with my Android app.
I've already added the simple-odf-0.8.2-incubating-jar-with-dependencies, but I get an error.

Are there other methods to recommend or tips?

```
07-10 20:49:11.024 18550-18550/de.***********.printodtfile D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-10 20:49:11.024 18550-18550/de.***********.printodtfile E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.***********.printodtfile, PID: 18550
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory;
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.rdfa.SAXRDFaParser.createInstance(SAXRDFaParser.java:59)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.initialize(OdfFileDom.java:217)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfManifestDom.initialize(OdfManifestDom.java:74)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.<init>(OdfFileDom.java:132)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfManifestDom.<init>(OdfManifestDom.java:63)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.newFileDom(OdfFileDom.java:189)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.parseManifest(OdfPackage.java:1187)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.readZip(OdfPackage.java:454)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.initializeZip(OdfPackage.java:425)
        at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.<init>(OdfPackage.java:285) etc.
```

Comment: Could you provide your gradle file where this is imported?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that dependency is trying to use a java file in the javax package that isn't included in the Android package [index](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages), but it's odd that if it's "with dependencies" that it still doesn't work.  From the provided context, I'm assuming you're adding the dependency as a .jar file.  Have you tried it as a gradle dependency?

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.odftoolkit/simple-odf
implementation group: 'org.apache.odftoolkit', name: 'simple-odf', version: '0.8.2-incubating'
```

Comment: ok I think it has brought something but now I get something new

`Process: de.carolus.printodt, PID: 23777
                  javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxOutputFactory not found`
I have found a approach, but the links are broken
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176028/how-writing-xml-file-usning-xmlstreamwriter-in-android)

an idea ?
or should I leave with the odt toolkit?

Comment: Have you tried using 'api' instead of implementation?  It's obviously still a dependency error you may need to include other things to fix, but try that instead of 'implementation', do a clean/build and see if the error is the same.