# How can I serialize a dom element to xml in the android sdk?

Tags: android, xml

org.w3c.dom.Element to String(XML)?

The typical use of LSSerializer does not work as there is no implementation available in android.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to depend on what api level you are targeting. If it is 8 or above,
see the plugminds answer to a related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/3551691/1148030