# org.w3c.dom.Document to String without javax.xml.transform

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I've spent a while looking around on Google for a way to convert a org.w3c.dom.Document to a string representation of the whole DOM tree, so I can save the object to file system.

However all the solutions I've found use javax.xml.transform.Transformer which isn't supported as part of the Android 2.1 API. How can I do this without using this class/containing package?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android.

Comment: @Javanna Thanks. Post as answer and i'll give you accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid using `Transformer` you should manually iterate over your xml tree, otherwise you can rely on some external libraries. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android).

Answer (score 5):

Please try this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("/path/to/file.xml");
DOMImplementation domImpl = ownerDocument.getImplementation();
DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS)domImpl.getFeature("LS", "3.0");
LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", Boolean.valueOf(false));
LSOutput lsOutput = domImplLS.createLSOutput();
lsOutput.setCharacterStream(output);
serializer.write(doc, lsOutput);
```

Comment: Nice, but not supported by org.w3c.tidy.DOMDocumentImpl for example.

Comment: JTidy doesn't implement LSSerializer