# Creating an xml document in android

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

So I'm trying to create an xml document in my android application. I'm using the code that I used when writing a java application. I tried as shown below:

```
public void createxml() throws SAXException, IOException {
        try {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "newxml.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

            // root elements
            // Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

            // Element rootElement = doc.get
            // doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            Node node = doc.getDocumentElement();

            // staff elements
            Element outfit = doc.createElement("outfit");
            node.appendChild(outfit);

            // set attribute to staff element
            /*
             * Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id"); attr.setValue("1");
             * staff.setAttributeNode(attr);
             */
            // shorten way
            // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

            // firstname elements


            if (savename.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element nameelement = doc.createElement("name");
                nameelement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(savename));
                outfit.appendChild(nameelement);
            }
            if (hatloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element hatelement = doc.createElement("hat");
                hatelement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(hatloc));
                outfit.appendChild(hatelement);
            }

            if (shirtloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element shirtelement = doc.createElement("shirt");
                shirtelement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(shirtloc));
                outfit.appendChild(shirtelement);
            }
            if (pantloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element pantselement = doc.createElement("pants");
                pantselement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(pantloc));
                outfit.appendChild(pantselement);
            }

            if (shoeloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element shoeselement = doc.createElement("shoes");
                shoeselement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(shoeloc));
                outfit.appendChild(shoeselement);
            }

            if (acc1loc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element accelement = doc.createElement("accessories");
                accelement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(acc1loc));
                outfit.appendChild(accelement);
            }

            if (acc2loc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element acc2element = doc.createElement("accessories2");
                acc2element.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(acc2loc));
                outfit.appendChild(acc2element);
            }

            if (beltloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element beltelement = doc.createElement("belt");
                beltelement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(beltloc));
                outfit.appendChild(beltelement);
            }

            if (dressloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element dresselement = doc.createElement("dress");
                dresselement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(dressloc));
                outfit.appendChild(dresselement);
            }

            if (jacketloc.equals("none")) {

            } else {
                Element jacketelement = doc.createElement("jacket");
                jacketelement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(jacketloc));
                outfit.appendChild(jacketelement);
            }

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
                    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "images" + File.separator
                            + "newxml.xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        hatloc = "none";
        shirtloc = "none";
        pantloc = "none";
        shoeloc = "none";
        acc1loc = "none";
        acc2loc = "none";
        beltloc = "none";
        dressloc = "none";
        jacketloc = "none";
        savename = "none";

    }
```

Everything worked fine until I got to this section below. I think it's the section where the xml file i created gets written. Does anyone know of a way to do this that works in android?

The code breaks with the `TransformerFactory`, `Transformer`, `DOMSource`, `StreamResult` and `TransformerException`.

```
    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(
            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                    + "images" + File.separator + "newxml.xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `Transfomer` class is not included in the Android API you're using.
To avoid using `Transformer` you should manually iterate over your xml tree, otherwise you can rely on some external libraries. You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android).

Comment: Would i be able to do that by using my existing code on the top and then replacing the bottom section?

Comment: @Peter I'm not an android expert but I think so.

Comment: you saved my life, from that code line my program control simply does not return.