# Android opera supports url but not default webview .. how to overcome?

Tags: android, url, webview, opera

`Android` **opera** supports url but not **default webview** . How to overcome this one? I have attached the url.

URl:  [Click here for url](http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=MA124CA0B5C008.RedFlagWarning.124CA0B6FD9CMA.BOXRFWBOX.835121ef7181220c68e2838a75b2cb97)

Comment: Be more specific: What exactly does not work? Errors?

Comment: @ Thommy above URL doesn't load fully (images, tags not showing) in android 2.2 and 2.3 series(as a web view and browser ) ...but it working 3.0 .. and higher versions... how to give support to that 2.2 series ????

Comment: Hi all , still i am searching the answer for this .. if any one found please advice me ..... i have tried with following sample also .. but not solved the problem . URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470263/android-xsl-transformation-null-pointer-but-working-on-desktop