# How to take backup for installed packages?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an application for taking backup for my device. How can I write this?  Till now, I've got all the installed packages list and I'm placing 3 buttons for taking the backup(Backup, CheckAll, Cancel).

If I'm going to take backup button it contains one alertdialog it shows 3 options (now, later, cancel). How to take backup the installed packages to one new list and it'll shows by date and time. How can I do this?  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if its possible to do that. I remember that i read in an article that in order to access to other packages you need to use the same user that the app does, and from my point of view that means that all the applications that are going to be backed up need to have the same user. I'm not an android expert but i think it wouldn't be possible to gain access to the other packages if you try Java IO to read the files as you normally do.
Good luck, maybe someone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by `backup installed packages`.
Generally users keep backup of their `database and preferences data`.
If you want to take a backup of your database and preference then you can create xml of your database and preferences using xml-serialization.

More information about xml-serialization [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android/2296051#2296051)

And also you can refer inbuilt facility for get backup [Click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)