# I want to backup all my android phone book contacts into an XML file

Tags: android, contacts

How can I store and reload my Android contacts in XML format.

Please can you give me some suggestions or some sample code?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Or would it be better if you posted on http://android.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

E.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0/1780818#1780818) might be helpful for reading contact data.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android/2296051#2296051) for writing XML.