# Reading and Writing XML file

Tags: android, xml, file-io, sd-card

I have an Application in which first I want to create a backup of message from inbox and store it into `backup.xml` file which is stored at `SDCARD/MYBACKUP/mybackup.xml`

Now I want to retrieve data, stored on `SDCARD/MYBACKUP/mybackup.xml`  and display all messages in listview.

Comment: so what you want ? How to create backup xml ? or How to read from that xml ?

Comment: how to read from that xml?
I have used XmlSerializer for creating an Xml file for inbox messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Writing XML file to sdcard see this answeer [Qberticus's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android)

android Reading file is just simple you have to use Xml parsing [See This for XML parsing](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/02/androidxml-parsing-common-class.html)

**To R/W Sdcard You have to give Permission**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: work but cant open my .xml file.

Error message like "error:couldn`t open mnt/sdcard/mybackup/abc.xml".

Comment: check you have mention permission for sdcard.See answer i have edited.and if problem solve then please accept it as answer