# how to create main.xml dynamically in android using java code?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am try to make one xml code to dynamically without need xml. its using java code only. anybody help me how to make javacode for this xml content. i do't want to use my main.xml in resource.

```
     <FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/applicationframe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFEEEEEE">
            <com.pdfplugin.QScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/pagepane"
                    android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.pdfplugin.QScrollView>


            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgclose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_gravity="top|right"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/readclose" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: why? and do you want to create an xml or do you want to create the layout only?

Comment: yes i will make one plugin but there i do't want to use xml i wan use this with javacode

Comment: see http://www.anddev.org/write_a_simple_xml_file_in_the_sd_card_using_xmlserializer-t8350.html and expand the code

Comment: also see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-androidxml/index.html

Comment: i want create main.xml dynamically and use in setcontentView()

Comment: look at the SO qustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290945/writing-xml-on-android

Comment: thanks @Rachel Gallen  I thinks it's work.. Thanks dear

Comment: As far as I know you can't create an XML file during runtime and use the same as a resource. The reason is obvious: If you use ids, the ids should be contained in the generated R file which can't be modified during runtime...

Comment: @WarrenFaith You could use tags and avoid the ids problem. But as you already said, you can't use your own created xml file as android pre proceses the xml layout files.

Comment: i need to do xml layout dyanmically with java code how to do this do u hava any idea.??  @ Luksprog